# SELECT rows according to another table

Tags: t-sql

Table A (Id, Value), Table B(AId, Value). I need to select only rows from A, for which the pair (Id, Value) is not in table B. Solution with "JOIN" would probably better, because of performance.

Comment: What `UNIQUE` constraints are there on the tables?

Comment: A.Id only. You can also assume B.Id (not B.AId) if you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various ways to do this type of query (called anti-join or anti-semijoin):

- Correlated `NOT EXISTS` subquery. In my opinion, the most self explanatory:

  ```
  SELECT a.*
  FROM a
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
        ( SELECT 1
          FROM b
          WHERE b.id = a.id
            AND b.value = a.value
        ) ;
  ```
- `LEFT JOIN` with `IS NULL` check. Very common solution, too, but not necessarily more efficient than the `NOT EXISTS` version:

  ```
  SELECT a.*
  FROM a
    LEFT JOIN b
      ON  b.id = a.id
      AND b.value = a.value
  WHERE b.id IS NULL ;
  ```
- There is the `EXCEPT` option as well, which is self explanatory as well but has 2 major restrictions:

  Works only if for the `SELECT` list, you need only the two columns (`a.id` and `a.value`) that are used in the join. If more columns from `a` are needed, use one of the previous options.
  Table `a` has a `UNIQUE` constraint on either `(id)`, `(id, value)` or `(value)`. Otherwise, the query will remove duplicates as well:

  ```
  SELECT a.id, a.value
  FROM a
  EXCEPT
  SELECT b.id, b.value
  FROM b ;
  ```